# Symfony 3.4 deployer fails due to permission denied of shared folder

Tags: symfony, deployment, permissions

I have developed a webapp based on Symfony3.4. On production it is deployed on a Ubuntu 18.04 Server via deployer (deployer.org).
Everything runs fine so far. The webapp is deployed in /opt/app/prod done by a user that is part of group www-data.

My webapp allows the upload of files. To support this I have added the folder data which stores the uploaded files.

In order to sustain access to the files after another release I have added the data folder to the list of shared folders.

My deploy.php looks as follows:

```
set('bin_dir', 'bin');
// Symfony console bin
set('bin/console', function () {
    return sprintf('{{release_path}}/%s/console', trim(get('bin_dir'), '/'));
});

// Project name
set('application', 'appname');
set('http_user', 'www-data');
set('writable_mode', 'acl');

// Project repository
set('repository', '<MY_GITREPO>');

// [Optional] Allocate tty for git clone. Default value is false.
set('git_tty', true);

// Shared files/dirs between deploys
add('shared_files', []);
add('shared_dirs', ['data']);


// Writable dirs by web server
add('writable_dirs', ['{{release_path}}','data']);


// Hosts
host('prod')
    ->hostname('<MY_HOST>')
    ->user('<MY_USER>')
    ->stage('prod')
    ->set('deploy_path', '/opt/app/prod/<MY_APPNAME>');
```

This leads to the following folder structure:

```
.
├── current -> releases/5
├── releases
│   ├── 2
│   ├── 3
│   ├── 4
│   └── 5
└── shared
    ├── app
    └── data
```

So everything fine so far - with one exception:
Deployer wants to setfacl the data folder which is not allowed as the files in data belongs to www-data:www-data where deployer tries to change this as .

```
The command "export SYMFONY_ENV='prod'; cd /opt/app/prod/<MY_APPNAME>/releases/5 && (setfacl -RL -m u:"www-data":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX /opt/app/prod/<MY_APPNAME>/releases/5)" failed.
setfacl: /opt/app/prod/<MY_APPNAME>/releases/5/data/child/679/ba7f9641061879554e5cafbd6a3a557b.jpeg: Operation not permitted
```

I have the impression that I did a mistake in my deployer.php or I missed something.
Has someone an idea what I need to do in order to get my deployment running?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Just to get this right. `/opt/app/prod/<app>/releases` is owned by `www-data:www-data` and group-writeable, you're deploying as a different user `user-x` who is member of `www-data` and the command `setfacl -RL -m u:"www-data":rwX -m u:user-x:rwX /opt/app/prod/<MY_APPNAME>/releases/5` fails? Can you confirm/double-check all files in the `shared/data` folder and especially the file `child/679/ba7f9641061879554e5cafbd6a3a557b.jpeg` are owned by `www-data:www-data` ?

Comment: No, /opt/app/prod/<app>/releases is owned by <MY_USER>:www-data but the given folder and all subfolder are group-writeable.  
And yes, I am trying to deploy as <MY_USER>.  
Just checked: All files in shared/data are owned by www-data:www-data as it has been created by the webserver.